# Append array data to a html table column-wise using only javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have an set of array

```
Case =[case1, case2,case3]
Condition = [condition1,condition2,condition3]
Observation = [obs1,obs2,obs3]
```

How can I display this in a html table with the below format? Case condition and observation are headers which don't change. Basically the number of columns doesn't change only the rows change. How can I do this using javascript?

I am new to javascript and I am having difficulty in iteration.

```
+----------------------------------
| Case  | Condition  | Observation| 
+---------------------------------+
| case1 | condition1 | obs1       |
+---------------------------------+
| case2 | condition2 | obs2       | 
+---------------------------------+
| case3 | condition3 | obs3       | 
+---------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Try following **JS**:

```
Case =["case1", "case2","case3"];
Condition = ["condition1","condition2","condition3"];
Observation = ["obs1","obs2","obs3"];

for(i=0;i<Case.length;i++)
{
    document.getElementById(tableid).innerHTML+="<tr><td>"+Case[i]+"</td><td>"+Condition[i]+"</td><td>"+Observation[i]+"</td></tr>"
}
```

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e3PXt/)